# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0 mono raspbian

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been following this post http://www.raspberry-sharp.org/eric-bezine/2012/10/mono-framework/installing-mono-raspberry-pi/ and have also copied my executable over to my raspberry pi.  I then tried to execute the program however it throws an exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok   en=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
```

Comment: Did you try to run: "sudo apt-get install mono-complete"

Comment: I shall try that now